# Convert normal pdf into lognormal pdf

Tags: probability, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have fitted a mixture of 3 normal distributions to my log-transformed data **Y**, as the package I'm using cannot fit a mixture of lognormal distributions.

**My questions is: how I can convert pdf from 3 normal distributions into lognormal pdf?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is just the same mixture of the associated log-normal PDFs. Your mixture model says that $\log Y|\mu \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, so $Y|\mu$ has a log normal distribution. The distribution of $\mu$ (a discrete distribution on 3 values) is the same.